# Can I use std::less to compare two arrays of char?

Tags: c++

I have this function `compare` that is a function template instantiated to compare two arrays of characters of different sizes:

```
template <unsigned N, typename M>
bool compare(char const (&a)[N], char const (&b)[M]){
    //    return strcmp(a, b); // Ok
    return std::less<char const(&)[N]>(a, b); // error here.
}
```

- It works just fine calling `strcmp` inside `compare` but how can I use `std::less` to compare them?
- How can I instantiate `std::less<?>` for the type of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Why do you insist on `less`? `std::less<std::string_view>` could work.

Comment: If you want to compare the contents of the strings, then `strcmp` is the tool to use

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes I really use it but only for curiosity sake can I use `std::less` for arrays?

Comment: Do you want to compare null-terminated strings, pointers, or sized buffers?

Comment: `std::less` calls `operator <`.  There is no `operator <` for arrays.  You could use the `operator <` to compare pointers to the arrays, but that doesn't really tell you anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ok get it thank you!

Comment: Look into `<algorithm>` for [`std::lexicographical_compare_three_way()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare_three_way). Or the older but less capable brother.

Comment: Worth keeping in mind that `strcmp` expects `a` and `b` to be `NUL` terminated, and only compares the text up to the `NUL`.  If the `N` or `M` characters do not include a `NUL`, it may read past the end of your character array buffers and have *undefined behaviour*.  (If your attempt at using less had worked, it would have only "worked" safely if `N <= M` and you *wanted* the first N characters compared, whether `NUL` or not.  If you want behaviour more like that, read up on [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) too.).

Comment: Even if `std::less` was the right tool for this, you are trying to construct it with `a` and `b` and return that instance. `std::less` doesn't have such a constructor and `std::less` isn't implicitly convertible to `bool`. You must first construct it, then call it: `std::less<char const(&)[N]>{}(a, b)` - but as mentioned - it's the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 3):

Foundamentally, you are trying to comparing two values with two different types: `char const (&a)[N]` vs `char const (&a)[M]`. However std::less can only compare two values with the same type. So to make it work:

```
#include <iostream>
template <unsigned N>
bool compare(char const (&a)[N], char const (&b)[N]){
    return std::less<char const[N]>()(a, b);
}

int main() {
  char const a[2] = {'a', 'a'};
  char const b[2] = {'a', 'a'};
  compare<2>(a, b);
}
```

Separately, one minor problem you have to fix: you need to use

```
std::less<char const[N]>()(a, b)
```

in stead of

```
std::less<char const[N]>(a, b)
```

`std::less<char const[N]>()` is used to create the std::less instance, and then you call the `operator()` on that instance.